# Lucene scoring: get cosine similarity as scores

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search, text-mining

I'm trying to solve nearest neighbor search problem.
Here is my code:

```
// Indexing
val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()
val directory = new RAMDirectory()
val config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
val iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config)

val queryField = "fieldname"
stringData.foreach { str =>
  val doc = new Document()
  doc.add(new TextField(queryField, str, Field.Store.YES))
  iwriter.addDocument(doc)
}
iwriter.close()

// Searching
val ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory)
val isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader)

val parser = new QueryParser(queryField, analyzer)
val query = parser.parse("Some text for testing")

val hits = isearcher.search(query, 10).scoreDocs
```

When I look on the value hits I see scores more then 1.

As far as I know, lucene scoring formula is:

```
score(q,d) = coord-factor(q,d) · query-boost(q) · cosSim(q,d) · doc-len-norm(d) · doc-boost(d)
```

But I want to get only cosine similarity in range[0,1] between query and document instead of  coord-factor, doc-len-norm and so on. 
What is a possible way to achieve it?

Comment: One thing to note: That similarity formula is no longer the default. As of 6.0, Lucene uses a [BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) implementation, by default. The old default is still available, see [ClassicSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ClassicSimilarity.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have gone through this official [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), you would realize that the rest of the terms in the `score` expression is important and makes the scoring process more logical and coherent.

But still if you want to achieve a scoring process using only Cosine Similaity, then you can write your custom similarity class. I have used different types of similarity method for document retrieval in my [class assignment](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~hw5x/Course/IR2015/_site/mps/2015/11/12/mp3/). So, in short you can write your own similarity method and assign it to the Lucene's `index searcher`. I am giving an example here which you modify to accomplish what you want.

Write your custom class (you just need to override one method in your class).

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BasicStats;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.SimilarityBase;

public class MySimilarity extends SimilarityBase {

    @Override
    protected float score(BasicStats stats, float termFreq, float docLength) {
        double tf = 1 + (Math.log(termFreq) / Math.log(2));
        double idf = Math.log((stats.getNumberOfDocuments() + 1) / stats.getDocFreq()) / Math.log(2);
        float dotProduct = (float) (tf * idf);
        return dotProduct;
    }

}
```

Then assign your implemented method to `index searcher` for relevance calculation as below.

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath)));
IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
indexSearcher.setSimilarity(new MySimilarity());
```

Here, i am using tf-idf dot product to compute similarity between query and documents. Formula is,

[image]

Two things need to be mentioned here are:

- **stats.getNumberOfDocuments()** returns total number documents in the index.
- **stats.getDocFreq()** returns document frequency for a term appeared in both query and document.

Lucene will now call the `score()` method that you have implemented to compute relevance score for each of the matched terms; terms that appeare both in query and documents.

This is not an straight forward answer to your question i know but you can use the approach i mentioned above in anyway you want. I implemented 6 different scoring technique in my homework assignment. I hope it will help you too.